# Javascript - table header center align

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I am creating a table as follows

```
table = document.createElement('table');
table.style.textAlign = 'center';
table.setAttribute('border', '2');

var thead = document.createElement('thead');
thead.style.color = "fuchsia ";
thead.style.textAlign = 'center';
```

When I populate the table, the row content is center aligned as expected but the header row is always left aligned. What can I do to make it center aligned?

Thanks

Comment: @oGeez Actually I am creating the table dynamically inside a js file.
I use `var resultDiv = document.getElementById("resultDiv"); 
document.createElement('table');`

Comment: I know sorry I rushed the reading. You will need row and cell elements inside your `thead`.

Comment: Klors solution fixed it for me. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`thead` is a container for `th`'s. The `th`'s always need to fill the `thead` and so the natural place to centre align things for a header row is within the `th`'s, so...

```
var th = document.createElement('th');
th.style.color = "fuchsia ";
th.style.textAlign = 'center';
```

<strike>Oh, and also, your `thead` hasn't got the centre alignment set, you're setting it on the table twice.</strike>

Comment: sorry there was a typo in the question, I am infact setting the textAlign on the header.